# Using JQuery, how can we use one function to use for click event of multiple buttons to display a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 app, I have a view with some embedded partial views each of which have a help button with IDs HelpButtonID_1, HelpButtonID_2,.... Moreover, each view has a div tag with text related to that partial view. The IDs of these div tags are divID_1, divID_2,...In my _Layout.cshtml view used by all the views, I have defined the jquery dialog box as follows so that when user clicks on the help button of a particular partial view, say View1 the dialog box would open with the text from the divID_1, and if the help button of partial View2 is clicked, the dialog box would open with the text from divID_2, etc.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
     $('[id^="divID_"]').dialog({
     width: 400,
     autoOpen: false
    });
    $('[id^="HelpButtonID_"]').click(function () {
      $('[id^="divID_"]').dialog("open");
      return false;
    });
 });
</script>
```

But the above is not working. On the other hand the the following works if I have a help button with ID, say, HelpButtonID and a div tag with ID, say, divID, on just one partial view.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#divID").dialog({
         width: 400,
         autoOpen: false
    });
    $('#HelpButtonID').click(function () {
       $("#divID").dialog("open");
       return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use same class on all buttons and then Do: `$('.SameClass').click(function () {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a common class for the buttons and dialogs, and a `data-` attribute to specify the dialog div:

```
<button class="help-button" data-dialog-id="#HelpDialog6">?</button>
```

---

```
<div id="HelpDialog6" class="help-dialog">Some content</div>
```

---

```
$(function () {
      $(".help-dialog").dialog({
         width: 400,
         autoOpen: false
    });
    $('.help-button').click(function () {
       $($(this).data('dialog-id')).dialog("open");
       return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Jason, your code is not working. I noticed that `$(this).data('dialog-id')` returns undefined when I add `alert($(this).data('dialog-id'))` in the click event of your code above. The button and div tag are exactly the same as in your example.

Comment: Hm, that is odd. It appears to work in this fiddle, can you see any differences? http://jsfiddle.net/3fLbS/

Comment: Jason, thank you for helping me and probably many other readers of this post. It's working now. I was using the `data-` attribute name as `data-dialogID` - and `$(this).data('dialogID')` - instead of `data-dialog-id`. I thought you could use `data-` attribute name as `data-anything`. Don't know why would then `data-dialogID` not work.

Comment: @nam There are some... quirks, maybe... with jQuery's `.data` and case-sensitivity that I don't fully understand, but avoid by using lowercase `data-` attributes.